# Stop alert box in vscode when debugging .NET Core API

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing an API using c# in .NET Core in Visual Studio Code on a Mac. When I press **F5** to debug, I get an alert box with the text **Do you want Code to open the external website?**. I usually just close this box by pressing **escape**. This process becomes tedious when you have to rebuild the API many times and every time you have to wait for the alert box just to close it to finish the build.

Any idea how to stop the dialog box from appearing?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

1. Open `launch.json`
2. Remove the `serverReadyAction` object.

Now the API starts without the alert or tab opening in browser.